# Magento 1.9.2.4 product thumbnail image not showing in grid/list view

Tags: php, image, magento

I've installed Magento 1.9.2.4. I imported the products and the store data from magento 1.4 using sql. I putted the media folder from the old site to the new site. The thumbnail image is replaced by placeholder only in product listing, on every category. If I click on a product, I have all the images.

In the backend are checked all boxes from images. I have right permissions on media/catalog/product folder. I have php memory set to 2048M, so I don't think that this is the problem. I also have installed gd library.

Please give me an advice.
[image: Print screen from my website]

UPDATE: Fixed.

I didn't find a solution using cache images.

I used the following code to display images in the product category grid:

```
 <img src="<?php $product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
         $thumbUrl = $product->getThumbnailUrl(200, 200);
           echo $thumbUrl; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" width="200" height="200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only thing that wasn't done in your migration was flushing the image cache. To do so, go into the admin backend and navigate to `System > Cache Management > Flush Catalog Images Cache`.

Note that this will affect load times of pages into cache again as it needs to regenerate the resized images.

Answer (score 0):

and please check media directory rights, try to set 777 for the moment

Comment: also if you added those products programaticaly, check if you checked base image

Comment: and reindex catalog indexes :)

Comment: I have this right on media folder. I added the products manually, just copy and paste in sql. I've done also the reindexing process. Base image is checked. :( I don't understand why in the product grid the thumbnail image is not showing, but in the right of the site, on recent products, is showing the image. It's the same code.